# Mongoose: automatically embed field upon create?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Say I have one model, `Book`, and another model, `Genre`. When I create the book, I'd like to be able to pass a `Genre` ID and have the model *automatically fetch and embed the document*. For example:

```js
const bookSchema = new Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  author: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  genre: {
    type: ObjectId,
    required: true,
  }
});

const genreSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
});
```

Then I'd like to be create a book as follows:

```js
const Book = await Book.create({
  title: 'Lord of the Rings',
  author: 'J. R. R. Tolkien',
  genre: '5d6ede6a0ba62570afcedd3a',
});
```

That would create a book and *automatically embed the genre document from the given ID*. Is there a way to do that from within the schema, or would I have to wrap it in additional logic?

Comment: You will have to wrap in an additional logic. One way is to use a pre-save hook, which will run before every save operations

Comment: @thammada.ts can you give an example of how I would do this? When I try setting this.genre in the pre-save hook, it does not change the value in the database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the pre-save mongoose [middleware/hook](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#pre) to find the genre and set it as an embedded document. In mongoose pre-save hook, `this` will be the current document, you can read the value and set the value to `this` object before it is written to the database.

Note that, since this is a pre-**save** hook, it will be run only on `Model.create()` or `document.save()`. So it won't be run on `Model.insertMany()`. **But** it will be run when you update the document using `document.save()`. If you want to set the genre only on new documents, you will have to check for `this.isNew` property

```
const { Schema, Types } = mongoose
const genreSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
});
const Genre = mongoose.model('Genre', genreSchema)

const bookSchema = new Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  author: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  genreId: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true,
  },
  genre: {
    type: genreSchema,
  },
});

bookSchema.pre('save', async function() {
  if (this.isNew) { // this.isNew will be true on only new documents
    this.genre = await Genre.findById(this.genreId) // `this` is the new book document
  }
})

const Book = mongoose.model('Book', bookSchema)

/* Test book creation */
const genre = await Genre.create({
  name: 'Fantasy'
})

const book = await Book.create({
  title: 'Lord of the Rings',
  author: 'J. R. R. Tolkien',
  genreId: genre._id,
});

console.log(book)
```

Comment: Is there a way to have the genreId property also called genre? Because this is for an API I would ideally want to be able to pass the ID as the name of the property the document will occupy.

Comment: Since what you in the `genre` field will be validated against what you declared in the schema. If you specify the `genre` field to be of type `genreSchema` it will fail the validation when you initially set it as a `String` or `ObjectId`. You can set `genre` type as `Schema.Types.Mixed`, but I don't think it's a good idea

Comment: Or you could [create a custom schema type](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/customschematypes.html)

Comment: With the `Mixed` schema or a custom schema type?

Comment: With the custom schema. Can you add a sample to your answer please?

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't get it working with a custom schema type.

Comment: I wasn’t able to either. Thanks anyway.

Comment: It works with Mixed schema type see code sample in my answer. You do not need to define separate schema for genre

Answer (score 1):

you can use mixed schema type and document middleware to solve your problem.see my sample code below:

```
const genreSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
});

const Genre = mongoose.model('Genre', genreSchema);

const bookSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    author: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    genre: {
        type: Object,
        required: true,
    }
});
bookSchema.pre('save', async function () {
    const genreID = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(this.genre);
    this.genre = await Genre.findById(genreID);

});

const Book = mongoose.model('Book', bookSchema);
const newBook = new Book({ title: 'The book', author: 'xyz', genre: '5ef55c67be27fb2a08a1131c' });
newBook.save();
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you know which genre ID to embed? Can you send this from your frontend?

If yes, then simply select the genre ID from you frontend and then pass it in your API's request body.

While in your backend:

```
router.route('/book')
    .post((req, res) => {
        Book.create({
            title: req.body.title,
            author: req.body.author,
            genre: req.body.genre,

        }, (err, product) => {
            if (err) {
                res.send(err);
            } else {
                res.json({success:true})
            }
        });
    })
```

Do something like this to create a new book object in your Book collection.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your question correctly I think what you're looking for is populate. https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

It would change your schema to look like the following

```
const bookSchema = new Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  author: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  genre: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Genre',
    required: true,
  }
});

const genreSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
});
```

When you get your book you can reference the genre by doing this

```
Book.find()
  .populate('genre')
```

Hopefully, that answered your question!

Comment: No, because I don’t want the subdocument to update if the genre document changes. I have a specific use case where the subdocument cannot change even if the original reference does. Does that make sense?